# echo 2 different url locations depending on form submit results

Tags: php, forms, form-submit, window.location

I have a form which is populating data from a database, the user selects the various rows of interest by clicking on a checkbox. All has been successfully working howver I am now trying to have the page redirect when the form is submitted go to one of 2 locations depending on the number of rows selected. (checkmarks checked.) Here is the current script condensed for security reasons.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$DELETE = "DELETE FROM job_picks WHERE ID='$userid'";

$wpdb->query($DELETE);


    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){

    $rowCount = count($_POST['ref']);


        for ($i=0; $i<$rowCount;$i++)
    {

            if ($selected == $_POST['ref'][$i])
                $compcode = $_POST['COMPCODE'][$i];

            $note = $_POST['note'][$i] ; // changed for security reasons
            $time = $_POST['time'][$i]; // changed for security reasons
            $date = $_POST['date'][$i]; // changed for security reasons



            $SQL = " left out for security reasons but is correctly populating data";

            $wpdb->query($SQL);

            echo "<script>window.location='https://example.com/step2/';</script>";



            } ?>

            <br class="clear">

        <?php } ?>

        <br class="clear">

    <?php } ?>

    <br class="clear">

 <?php }
 ?>
```

I tried changing the line

```
 echo "<script>window.location='https://example.com/step2/';</script>";
```

to

```
 if ($rowcount == 1) {
    echo "<script>window.location='https://example.com/step3/';</script>";
}
else 
    echo "<script>window.location='https://example.com/step2/';</script>";
```

but only seemed to send all results to step3 as opposed to only those submissions which only have one item checked. Any insight would be appreciated and snippets are always helpful thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure $rowcount gets the expected value? also, why don't you redirect with headers?

Comment: i went with the window.location due to when using headers some were saying that they were not being redirected.

Comment: if I remove the echo to redirect and replace it with an echo $rowCount; the page itself just reloads so I am not sure how to check this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

The reason they all go to three is you are doing a redirect inside a loop. Meaning, on loop iteration 0 you execute your `<script>window.location = 'bla'`, and it attempts to essentially redirect straight away (not straight away, but before the others have a chance to do anything)

You need to move the `if` clauses outside, and after, the loop block.

**Other notes**

- Please, do not feed `POST` variables straight into SQL queries. Please.
- Prefer PHP headers over script redirects. Your comment mentioned it not working, but you are using WP, consider even using the wp_redirect method https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/
- Remove the `<br/>`'s. If you have seperated your logic and view correctly, there is zero need for html littered in submit handlers

Comment: thanks Chris, I am going to look into this and see if I can sort it out. Really appreciate the insight.

Comment: Cool. Remember to upvote if useful, and mark as correct if it solved your problem

Comment: wicked insight mate, I pulled my if statement outside the loop or the redirects and voila its loading the correct pages. I am going to look into swapping out to the wp_redirect method next as well. much obliged you came by this post.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your `$rowCount` and `$rowount`, I hope this just typo.

and you can debug the value for each `$rowCount`in the loop. something like in your code for debug:

```
foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected){

    $rowCount = count($_POST['ref']);
    //print the debug data
    print_r($rowCount, true );
}
die();
```

also, make sure the `$_POST['ref']` is valid.

and still no clues what happened, please attach the debug data so others people might know what is the issue